# How to convert sound file to binary file and send in http post?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I recorded sound in file called "recordedTmpFile".now i want to send the file to server .

i tried this code

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"recordedTmpFile" ofType:@"caf"];

NSData *postData = [filePath dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
//nsdata to string  
  NSString *content = [[NSString alloc]  initWithBytes:[postData bytes]
                                               length:[postData length] encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

am getting null value in "content"

please help me to fix this problem

Answer (score 0):

Did your app record the sound and write it into the file? Remember that the app bundle is read-only, so if you tried to write the file to a location in the main bundle, as your code seems to indicate, then the write operation probably failed. If that's the case, then of course there's no file to read or send.

Try changing the path to which you record data to someplace in the documents directory, which is writeable.

Comment: i used the following code to store the recorded sound                            //Generate a temp file for use by the recording.
NSURL *recordedTmpFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:
        [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:
      [NSString stringWithFormat:
       @"Myrecording%d.%@",i++, @"caf"]]];
 NSLog(@"Using File called: %@",recordedTmpFile);

Comment: That's not the same as the path that you're trying to read from. You're trying to read from the main bundle, which a) isn't where you wrote the file, and b) again, isn't writeable.